# unable to open file: 'mask_rcnn_coco_h5' in pixellib python

Tags: python, python-3.x, image-segmentation, h5py, pixellib

This is my code (as per [pixellib documentation](https://www.stackoverflow.com/))

```
import pixellib
from pixellib.instance import instance_segmentation

segment_image = instance_segmentation(infer_speed = "rapid" )
segment_image.load_model("mask_rcnn_coco.h5")
segment_image.segmentImage("sample.jpg", show_bboxes = True, output_image_name = "new.jpg")
```

And then I get this error code:

```
 File "h5py\_objects.pyx", line 54, in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper
  File "h5py\_objects.pyx", line 55, in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper
  File "h5py\h5f.pyx", line 106, in h5py.h5f.open
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] Unable to open file (unable to open file: name = 'mask_rcnn_coco.h5', errno = 2, error message = 'No such file or directory', flags = 0, o_flags = 0)
```

I expected this to work successfully, as it was in the pixellib documentation. Unfortunately, I keep getting this error code even when trying semantic segmentation from pixellib.

If anyone has any feedback, it would be greatly appreciated.
I have been trying to solve this for days.

Note: I have already installed tensorflow, imgaug, and pixellib (with the upgrade).

Comment: The file `mask_rcnn_coco.h5` does not exist **in the current directory**.

Comment: @JohnGordon How would I go about pixellib instance segmentation?

Comment: I don't know what that means.

Comment: Since the file mask_rcnn_coco.h5 does not exist in the current directory, how could I iterate my code to minimize errors? What could I use to replace mask_rcnn_coco.h5? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does that file exist anywhere on your computer?

Comment: No, I have searched in all directories, but it is nowhere to be found.

Comment: Then how did you expect the code to work at all?  Clearly the code requires that file.

Comment: Wait, I have found it. It still does not seem to be working properly.

Comment: Then the file must not be in the current directory.  I already explained this.